# Changing Button Text Dynamically with jAlerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I'm having trouble doing a relatively simple task. I'm using jAlerts (http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/), which I'm aware is no longer supported, and trying to change the text of the buttons into a variable.

As of now, here is the beginning code of jAlerts, in which the buttons are defined as strings:

```
$.alerts = {

    // These properties can be read/written by accessing $.alerts.propertyName from your scripts at any time

    verticalOffset: -75,                // vertical offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels
    horizontalOffset: 0,                // horizontal offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels/
    repositionOnResize: true,           // re-centers the dialog on window resize
    overlayOpacity: .01,                // transparency level of overlay
    overlayColor: '#FFF',               // base color of overlay
    draggable: true,                    // make the dialogs draggable (requires UI Draggables plugin)
    okButton: 'Ok',         // text for the OK button
    cancelButton: 'Cancel', // text for the Cancel button
            deleteButton: 'Delete', // text for the remove button
    dialogClass: null,                  // if specified, this class will be applied to all dialogs
```

What I'm trying to do is replace those with variables (in this case I'm using a large JS array):

```
$.alerts = {

    // These properties can be read/written by accessing $.alerts.propertyName from your scripts at any time

    verticalOffset: -75,                // vertical offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels
    horizontalOffset: 0,                // horizontal offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels/
    repositionOnResize: true,           // re-centers the dialog on window resize
    overlayOpacity: .01,                // transparency level of overlay
    overlayColor: '#FFF',               // base color of overlay
    draggable: true,                    // make the dialogs draggable (requires UI Draggables plugin)
    okButton: property_dict['allDialog.OK.button.text'],         // text for the OK button
    cancelButton: property_dict['grid.Confirm.Delete.cancel'], // text for the Cancel button
            deleteButton: property_dict['grid.Confirm.Delete.remove'], // text for the remove button
    dialogClass: null,                  // if specified, this class will be applied to all dialogs
```

I see that at the top of the page, it says that these properties can be changed by accessing $.alerts.propertyName in your scripts -- the problem is, there seems to be no documentation anywhere on how to actually do this.

Can any jAlert ninjas out there help me out:?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do exactly what it said - "accessing $.alerts.propertyName in your scripts"

to change the text on the ok button:

```
$.alerts.okButton = 'string literal or variable here';
```

to change the text on the cancel button:

```
$.alerts.cancelButton = 'string literal or variable here';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was just having trouble without seeing a specific example.